# Java: Stepwise compilation

Tags: java, windows-7, compiler-construction, 64-bit, notepad++

I have been downloading a Java source file (.java-file) and it's a bit of a mess...
I am wondering if there are any known IDE or compilers that can compile the source code
step by step, telling how it compiles at each line of code and if there are any child-threads or threads ran simultaneously, it goes trough them both in a logical or understandable way that I can comment or modify the code, in other words; clean it up?

I am running a **Windows 7 64-bit** computer with the **IDE Notepad++**, if information needed.

Thanks for your time and answers!

Comment: Try using Eclipse or NetBeans or IdeaJ - these will show you all the compile errors.

Comment: I second Eclipse, and also used JCreator when I was first learning Java. That being said, you probably don't actually want to see the compilation step-by-step; you probably just want to see the compile errors.

Comment: Notepad++ is a text editor, not an IDE. If you use any real IDE, it will more or less do what you need.

Comment: "..if there are any child-threads or threads ran simultaneously.." <-- that's *not* compiling. You may be interested in [*code coverage*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage), static analysis, or refactoring tooling, etc.

Comment: IntelliJ is also pretty useful. It is extremely similar to Eclipse and you can find the download at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/